# Can i add solid background with center text in video as ending screen using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, text, ffmpeg

I would like to create a video consisting of some text.  The background should just be some color, I have already one video, In that i want to add solid background with text as just ending screen, but cant find anywhere how this could be done without a photo, just using text to create such video.

Can you help me ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use:

- [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) filter to make the colored background.
- [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter to automatically match the size of the main video.
- [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter (or [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter) to make text.
- [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) filter to generate silent audio for the ending screen which is required to concatenate to the main stream if it also contains audio.
- [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter to concatenate.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -t 5 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -filter_complex "color=duration=5:color=blue[bg];[bg][0]scale2ref[bg2][main];[bg2]setsar=1,drawtext=text='Ending':fontsize=20:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2[text];[main][0:a][text][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```